# How to use printout extension in my view page to print view page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, yii

I have created a yii based project. I have a view where we show data from a database. I want to print that page. I searched and found the printout extension for printing and I copied the 'print' directory to /protected/extensions, but we can not understand how we could use it on my view page to print it.

My view page:

```
    <div class="row">    

    <div class="row-column1">
            <?php echo CHtml::label('Reg. Number. :','student_enroll_no'); ?>
        <?php echo $info->student_enroll_no;?> 
    </div>

    <div class="row-column2">
            <?php echo CHtml::label('Adm. Date :','student_adm_date'); ?>
        <?php if($info->student_adm_date != NULL)
            echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($info->student_adm_date));?>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="row-column1">
        <?php echo CHtml::label('Student Name :','student_first_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $info->student_first_name;?>
    </div>

    <div class="row-column2">
    <?php echo CHtml::label('Enroll No. :','student_mobile_no'); ?>   
        <?php echo $info->student_mobile_no;?>


    </div>


</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="row-column1">
     <?php echo CHtml::label('Fathers Name :','student_last_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $info->student_last_name;?>
        <!--<?php echo CHtml::label('Gender :','student_gender'); ?>
        <?php echo $info->student_gender;?>-->
    </div>

    <div class="row-column3">
     <?php echo CHtml::label('Mothers Name :','student_mother_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $info->student_mother_name;?>
       <!-- <?php echo CHtml::label('Date of Birth :','student_dob'); ?>
    <?php   if($info->student_dob != NULL)
        echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($info->student_dob));?>-->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="row-column1">
    <?php echo CHtml::label('Gender :','student_gender'); ?>
        <?php echo $info->student_gender;?>
    <!--<?php echo CHtml::label('Course :','student_transaction_course_id'); ?>
        <?php
            echo !empty($model->student_transaction_course_id) ? $model->relCourse->course_name : 'N/A';

        ?>-->


    </div>

    <div class="row-column2">
     <?php echo CHtml::label('Date of Birth :','student_dob'); ?>
    <?php   if($info->student_dob != NULL)
        echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($info->student_dob));?>
        <!--<?php echo CHtml::label('Year :','student_academic_term_period_tran_id'); ?>
       <?php echo $model->Rel_student_academic_terms_period_name->academic_term_period;?>-->
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="row-column1">
<?php echo CHtml::label('Category :','title'); ?>
        <?php echo $info->title;?>


    </div>

    <div class="row-column2">
        <?php echo CHtml::label('Email ID :','student_email_id_1'); ?>                          <?php echo $info->student_email_id_1; ?>
    </div>  
</div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="row-left">
    <?php echo CHtml::label('Course :','student_transaction_course_id'); ?>
        <?php
            echo !empty($model->student_transaction_course_id) ? $model->relCourse->course_name : 'N/A';

        ?>

       <!-- <?php echo CHtml::label('Blood Group :','student_living_status'); ?>
        <?php echo $info->student_living_status; ?>-->
    </div>

    <div class="row-column3">

       <!-- <?php echo CHtml::label('Nationality :','student_transaction_nationality_id'); ?>
        <?php if($model->student_transaction_nationality_id!=null)
        echo $model->Rel_Nationality->nationality_name; 
    ?>-->
    <?php echo CHtml::label('Year :','student_academic_term_period_tran_id'); ?>
       <?php echo $model->Rel_student_academic_terms_period_name->academic_term_period;?>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="row-left">
        <?php echo CHtml::label('Subjects :','languages_known1'); ?>
        <?php 
        $knwLang = "";
        if($lang->languages_known1)
        $knwLang =  $lang->Rel_Langs1->languages_name; 
        if($lang->languages_known2)
        $knwLang .= ", ".$lang->Rel_Langs2->languages_name;
        if($lang->languages_known3)
        $knwLang .= ", ".$lang->Rel_Langs3->languages_name;
        echo $knwLang;
    ?>

    </div>
</div>





  <div class="row last">

        <?php echo ('_____________________Note -Click on edit and update DoB , Subjects and upload photo ,Enroll no. .'); ?>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for this extension says it is tuned for the dataGrid widget. However it seems you are not using the dataGrid widget so what you can do is override the default printedElement property.

**For example:**

Wrap all the elements you wish to print in a div and give it an id of #printme and add the following to your view.

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('application.extensions.print.printWidget', array(                   
                   'cssFile' => 'print.css',
                   'printedElement'=>'#printme',
                   )
                 )
               ); 
?>
```

NOTE: Don't forget to add/edit the print.css file.

Read the documentation for more options: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/printout